# ASP.net URL Routing from subfolders back to root

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

Here is a look at my Routes in my Global.aspx file

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "Home", "~/index.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("AboutUs", "AboutUs", "~/AboutUs.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("Tacos", "Tacos/{id}", "~/Products/Content.aspx")
```

I have a rather large menu for a site that is saved as a function that uses a StringBuilder to deliver the website menu in an asp:Panel on each page of the site, this way I'm only making changes in one place for the menu.

in the menu, I have normal HTML anchors like this

```
<a class='link' href='Home'><div>HOME</div></a>
<a class='link' href='AboutUs'><div>About Us</div></a>
<a class='link' href='/Tacos/Overview/'><div>Tacos Overview</div></a>
```

on loaded everything works fine, go to the About Us page, back to the Home page, all good. Then if I go to the Tacos page, and that works great. But trying to go back to the other pages fail. It builds on the route, i.e. [www.page.com/Tacos/Overview/Home/](http://www.page.com/Tacos/Overview/Home/) and of course, throws a 403 file not found error.

I'm sure this is something simple I'm missing...

Comment: Have you tried modifying your hrefs to add a slash in front of the URL?

Comment: That was it! I had tried adding slashes in the routing but not in the href, I knew it was something simple...

Comment: The problem that you tell the page I will give you route to the Tacos with `{id}`, so, Just remove the `{id}` or pass the `id` to the link, it should be work after that